# Given that $A$ is normal, show that there exists a matrix $B$ such that $B^k = A$, where $k \in \mathbb N$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

> Given that $A$ is normal, show that there exists a matrix $B$ such that $B^k = A$, where $k \in \mathbb N$

I do apologize. I originally posted the incorrect question with a proof to the incorrect question. Here it is revised.

I unfortunately am having a little bit of trouble understanding where to begin. I know that $A$ is normal means that $A^*A = AA^*$. Here's what I think might work:

I know that $A$ is normal implies $A$ is unitarily diagonalizable, i.e., for some unitary matrix $Q \in M_n(\mathbb C)$, $A = Q^*\Lambda Q$, where $\Lambda = \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n)$.

Instead, take $B = Q^*\Lambda_{\alpha} Q$, where $\Lambda_\alpha = \text{diag}\left(\sqrt[k]{\lambda_1}, \sqrt[k]{\lambda_2}, \ldots, \sqrt[k]{\lambda_n}\right).$ Then $$\begin{align}B^k &= \left(Q^*\Lambda_\alpha Q\right)^k \\ & = Q^*\Lambda_\alpha^kQ \\ &= Q^*\text{diag}\left(\left(\sqrt[k]{\lambda_1}\right)^k, \left(\sqrt[k]{\lambda_2}\right)^k, \ldots, \left(\sqrt[k]{\lambda_n}\right)^k\right) Q\\ &=Q^*\text{diag}\left(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n\right)Q \\ &= Q^*\Lambda Q \\ &= A.\end{align}$$ And we know that $B$ is normal because $$\begin{align}B^*B &= \left(Q^*\Lambda_\alpha Q\right)^*\left(Q^*\Lambda_\alpha Q\right) \\ &= Q^*\Lambda_\alpha^*QQ
^*\Lambda_\alpha Q \\&= Q^*\Lambda_\alpha^*\Lambda_\alpha Q \\ & = Q^*\Lambda_\alpha\Lambda_\alpha^*Q \tag{Since diagonal matrices commute}\\ &= Q^*\Lambda_\alpha QQ^*\Lambda_\alpha^*Q \\ &= BB^*.\end{align}$$

Is this even the correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your approach is the standard one. Notation-wise, though, $\lambda^{1/k}$ is not a good notation if $\lambda$ is not positive, because there is no canonical choice of a root.

Comment: Wait, do you mean to say that I *should* use $\lambda^{1/k}$ and *not* $\sqrt[k]{\lambda}$? I do understand that using the radical is probably poor choice, but I don't see why I *shouldn't* use $\lambda^{1/k}$. Or could you clarify what it is that you mean?

Comment: Neither. What is $(-1)^{1/4}$? Is it $e^{i\pi/8}$? Or $e^{5i\pi/8}$? Or $e^{9i\pi/8}$? Or $e^{13i\pi/8}$?

Comment: Okay. I understand now: I must use De Moivre's Theorem.

Comment: Yes, if you want to write them explicitly, which is not the point. The point is that "root" is not an "injective" notion, so it doesn't usually deserve its own notation. So you would say: let $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ such that $w_j^k=\lambda_j$.